# Inconsistent Outcome When Factoring $a^6 - b^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm trying to factor $$a^6-b^6.$$

I have two options here: factor $a^6$ and $b^6$ either as cubes or as squares. I tried to factor them as cubes but had a single incorrect sign in the outcome.

$$a^6-b^6=(a^2)^3-(b^2)^3 = (a^2-b^2)((a^2)^2+a^2b^2+(b^2)^2)$$
Now factor out the power 2:

$$a^6-b^6=(a+b)(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

The author of the exercise solves the exercise as follows:
$$(a^3)^2-(b^3)^2 = (a^3+b^3)(a^3-b^3)$$
$$a^6 - b^6 = (a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)(a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$$
$$a^6 - b^6 = (a + b)(a - b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$$

Notice the difference in sign of ab, once negative and once positive.

I fail to see the error in the way I solved it first.

Comment: You forgot the mixed terms, $(a^2+ab+b^2)^2\ne a^4+a^2b^2+b^4$

Comment: $a^6-b^6=(a+b)(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)(a^2 \color{red}{-}ab+b^2)$

Comment: "Now factor out the power 2". Remember in the future that this is not a thing you can do. Powers can come outside products, not sums.

Comment: Thanks I see my fault now, indeed taking out the power would yield a different result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(a^4+a^2b^2+b^4)=(a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2-a^2b^2)=(a^2+b^2-ab)(a^2+b^2+ab)$.

Comment: Could you clarify the $a^2b^2 = 2a^2b^2 - a^2b^2$ and how that translates to the $-ab$ and $+ab$ in the result as it is leaving me confused. Is this a special rule?  Thanks!

Comment: Okay I think I have figured it out. You write the $a^2b^2$ as $2a^2b^2-a^2b^2$ so you get the special identity $a^2 + 2ab + b^2= (a+b)(a+b)$

Now this leaves us with the $-a^2b^2$ to factor out which is $-ab*+ab$

Comment: @user3051847 $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$, $(a^2+b^2)^2=a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2$, and $a^2 b^2 = (ab)^2$.